# async being ignored within a for loop

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a div which I want to transition a varying amount of times, one after the other. The new locations of this div has been fed to the `movePlayer` function via an array called `journey`. This data is then converted into translate coordinates and set as a style on my div.

I have been trying for days to make a for loop wait until a `transitionend` event has triggered before continuing through its next iteration. The `listenForMoveFinish` function is correctly responding only when the transition is complete, but I cannot make the for loop wait for this reply before it charges onto the next iteration.

I've tried disabling rules with inline comments, separating sections of the for loop into separate async functions and moving the level of the promise, but I have no idea how to fix this. Apologies for lack of working code but there are a bunch of functions and an astar path finding library that get me to this point.

Can anyone suggest why this is not working?

```
function movePlayer(journey) {
  let timePlus100 = 100;//removed 'playerInfo.playerSpeed + ' to test
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    /* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
    for (let i = 0; i < journey.length; i++){
      (async function(){
        try {
          let nextX = journey[i].y;//?SWITCHED X AND Y AS ASTAR SWITCHES IN GRAPH
          let nextY = journey[i].x;//?SWITCHED X AND Y AS ASTAR SWITCHES IN GRAPH
          let fromTop = (26 + (nextX * 16) + (nextY * 16)) + "px";
          let fromLeft = (576 + (nextX * 32) - (nextY * 32)) + "px";
          let translateXYZ = "translate3d(" + fromLeft + ", " + fromTop + ", 0px)";
          document.getElementById("playerLayer").style.transform = translateXYZ;
          moveStatus = await listenForMoveFinish();
          if (i === journey.length - 1) {
            setTimeout(function(){resolve("complete"); }, timePlus100);
          }
        } catch (err) {
        }
      })();
    }
    /* eslint-enable no-await-in-loop */
  })
}

function listenForMoveFinish(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    playerLC.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
      resolve(2);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You forgot to wait for the resolution of the async IIFE in the loop

Comment: Also it seems you are resolving the same promise multiple times, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't think i can use `await async function(){` though as this is outside of the async function (i.e. itself)?

Comment: In that case you need to save all the promises in an array and use `Promise.all()` to wait for them.

Comment: you're correct - but then you don't need to be creating a `new Promise` in `function movePlayer` either

Comment: I looked at promise.all but the only examples I found were for known amounts of promises. My for array could be almost any length and I really cant get my head around how I would do that.

Comment: Promise.all isn't a good fit, since this code is attempting to run some transitions in serial, not parallel

Comment: @TameAim - yeah, but you still don't need to create that Promise - check this code https://jsfiddle.net/t2ehpbx4/

Comment: That works great Jaromanda X - I changed the `return new Promise...` line to simply `Promise.resolve()`, as the parent function was refusing to move on to its next task, and now its works perfectly - That must have been to do with the way I setup the async parent function which I did not post here. I was using set interval before I started this `transitionend` experiment but that resulted in some jerky and unpredictable behaviour when transitions had not ended before another began. The transitions are now much better. Thankyou

Comment: `I changed the return new Promise...` well, then it won't wait for `timePlus100` delay ... and there's no point at all in using Promise.resolve instead at that point - it does nothing

Comment: `timePlus100` is gone too. This was only there for me to see what was actually happening. Now each transition is seamlessly relying on completion of the previous. [updated Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dfx3g9uj/)

Comment: then remove the Promise.resolve - not need for that ... just return "complete" or do nothing :p

Comment: Even better. Thanks :D